# Excel will not update links, entire day of research and tests with random results

Tags: excel, vba

Short version, my Excel is set properly to automatically update links and all my files(locally stored) work fine for years. Suddenly one will not update linked data. I click on Connections>Edit connections>Check Status every linked file has "Warning! Values referring to other workbooks were not updated"

Refresh/calculate all does nothing.Changing to manual and doing this, back to auto, open and closing, restarting, using these same files on another PC. Nothing I did fixes it.

Clicking into an individual cell(F2) then back out though updates that one cell.
Open 
All security settings are correct I am 98% sure, regardless whatever settings I had haven't changed and it did work.

I read a post that seemed exactly the same but his solution was enable protected content. Not the case here, i disabled it fully. There seems to be an error causing this possibly..

Long version. This is my largest file I continue to build
I have a main excel sheet that is linked to 35 workbooks. The source workbooks have lists of 3-4 columns, ranging from 1,000-10,000 rows long. The main WB uses index match for each source to pull two small fields. It takes about 5-6mins to do a calculate all with a desktop i7 3.64ghz ivy with 16gb ram.I never have issues on. Win 10/64bit and office 2016 64bit.

Some source files are .xls, I am in the process of changing them to xlsx but when I open the xls file and the values update. I then save as xlsx with a shorter name as well (trying to lighten the formulas) I go back to Connections>Edit connections>Check Status and the same warning is there. However I can click update values and it says OK.

This is very important file and is not physically monitored. Until something sells wrong I realize it wasnt updated, I am hoping for a concrete answer I can solve instead of just changing random things and hoping.. all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Voting to close as off topic because it has absolutely nothing to do with programming as written. General software, computer and operating system questions should be posted on [su] instead. This site is for programming (code) and programmers tools related questions.

Comment: try saving it as .xlsb just in case.

Comment: Seems like Linked sheets are Limited by available memory https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-16c69c74-3d6a-4aaf-ba35-e6eb276e8eaa

Comment: This is not very helpful but... if you have a complex business critical system built in excel you need to probably start introducing things like change control. In a 'production' system, change is very heavily controlled. You always know what changes are made, when they are made, and how to easily roll them back. It seems to me that you did make a change (or someone else made a change, i.e. changed drive mappings etc.) and it has caused one linkage error which in turn has cascaded through the rest.

Comment: Can I suggest you first make a copy of the whole thing, then try manually adding workbooks one by one. You might find it's just one worksheet causing the problem. Also to find the problem you need to be methodical. If you randomly change stuff and manage to fix it and it happens again... you'll never know what the issue is. Are these source files on a local or remote drive?

Answer (score 0):

I actually resolved this by opening all source workbooks with the main workbook open and resaving them one by one (Status on some turned OK, most remained). Then I simply used Edit Links and Update Values for each connection which changed the status to OK. Saved the main workbook and no more issues..

Yes I need to take those suggestions and the workbook to the next level as it has clearly outgrown my skillset, but getting there..